# How to write a function that goes through every misspelled word in a buffer one by one?

Tags: flyspell

I wrote the following code to realize my preferred spellchecking scheme:

```
(defun flyspell-1by1-popup-correction ()
   "When this function is called it first marks all incorrect words in a buffer and then jumps to the first marked word and opens a pop up to correct it."
   (interactive)
   (flyspell-buffer)
   (beginnscraing-of-buffer)
   (org-next-visible-heading 1)
   (flyspell-goto-next-error)
   (flyspell-popup-correct))

(defun flyspell-1by1-popup-continue ()
   "Jump to next word marked as uncorrect and open popup."
   (interactive)
   (flyspell-goto-next-error)
   (flyspell-popup-correct))

(define-key flyspell-mode-map (kbd "C-.") #'flyspell-1by1-popup-correction)
(define-key flyspell-mode-map (kbd "C-,") #'flyspell-1by1-popup-continue)
```

Using the above functions I can hit "C-." to flyspell-buffer, jump to first misspelled word and open correction popup. I can then continue through the rest of the buffer by pressing "C-," , which will jump to the next misspelled word and open the correction popup.

This is okay-ish. What I want is a function which automatically goes on to jump to the next word and open the correction popups for as long as there are words marked as misspelled. I thought I could implement this with a while-loop, approximately like so:

```
(defun flyspell-1by1-popup-correction-until-end ()
"When this function is called it first marks all incorrect words in a buffer and then jumps to the first marked word and opens a pop up to correct it. The function then continues to jump to the next misspelled word for as long as there are misspelled words after the mark and opens a popup each time."
   (interactive)
  (flyspell-buffer)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (org-next-visible-heading 1)
  (while  (flyspell-goto-next-error)
     (flyspell-goto-next-error)
     (flyspell-popup-correct)))
```

but apparently `flyspell-goto-next-error` does not return a convenient boolean for me to use in the loop. Is there a way to check whether there is a misspelled word after the mark?

Comment: Are you aware of the `ispell` command?

Comment: Yes, I am. You are right. I basically want that but with the flyspell popup. Also the ispell command gets lost in my latex headers indefinitely.

Comment: Try changing the test to `(not (equal (flyspell-goto-next-error) "No more miss-spelled word!"))`. This is definitely a hack that will break if they correct the misspelling of `miss-spelled` :-) but it might work for now.

Comment: Or just `(not (flyspell-goto-next-error))`: that final `if` returns `nil` unless you have reached the end of the buffer.

Comment: BTW, you don't want to call `flyspell-goto-next-error` twice, as you are doing: once in the test, and once in the body of the loop. That's going to skip the first error. Just call it in the test only.

Comment: What @FranBurstall said: it's much more robust.

Comment: Thank you all! It works like a charm!

Comment: Unless @FranBurstall provides an answer of his own,  instead of adding the working function to your question, you should make it into an answer (yes, you can answer your own question - and you can even accept it after a couple of days).

Comment: I took the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last form in `flyspell-goto-next-error` is

```lisp
(if (= pos max)
    (message "No more miss-spelled word!"))
```

which will return `nil` unless you have reached the end of the buffer.  So the right test for you is:

```lisp
(while (not (flyspell-goto-next-error))
       (flyspell-popup-correct))
```